# Re-resizable preventing flatlist from scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, resizable

`Resizable` from the `re-resizable` package is preventing my Flatlist from scrolling. When the list has enough elements to require scrolling, it doesn't start to scroll. This behavior doesn't happen when the resizable element isn't there. The documentation for Resizable doesn't mention scrolling.

```
<Resizable
      style={style.mainViewExpanded}
      defaultSize={{
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      }}
      maxHeight="80vh"
      maxWidth="600"
      minWidth="300"
      minHeight="300"
      enable={{
        top: true,
        right: false,
        bottom: false,
        left: true,
        topRight: false,
        bottomRight: false,
        bottomLeft: false,
        topLeft: true,
      }}
    >
       <FlatList
            data={parsedPacks}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.packName}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <PackListItem
                packName={item.packName || pack}
                content={item.content}
              />
            )}
          />
</Resizable>
```

Styles:

```
mainViewExpanded: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: theme.BGSECOND,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: theme.FIRST,
  },
```

Comment: This is a react library as I can see

Comment: There is a react library, but I'm using a repackage of it. I'm seeing if I can reimplement this with the react library instead. I'm starting to feel like it might not be an issue with the resizable after all though. I might close the question until I know more.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use it with RN, Maybe try to investigate more

Comment: We can use it because we're using react native web :) I found the issue. It was a style issue. Overflow can prevent scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. `overflow` when set to `hidden` will prevent scrolling. This is documented in the CSS documentation. The way to solve this problem is by either setting `overflow` to `auto`, `hidden visible` or `visible hidden` depending on the situation. The reason is because `overflow` is a shorthand for `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`. The first word in the value is for `x`, and the second is for `y`.

```
mainViewExpanded: {
    overflow: 'hidden visible',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle scroll is to add

> overflow-y

or

> overflow-x

..depending on your data to

> auto